# Is it possible that the GMT time in idevice will be distorted?

Tags: ios, objective-c, timestamp, gmt

I have developed a program in Objective-C which sends a GMT timestamp to the server for sorting the data first. I wonder if there is any way to send the time to the server that is not true.

I use:

```
long long milliseconds = (long long)([[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000.0);
```

Comment: A user can set the time on their iOS device to anything they want.

Comment: You should generally not trust the client anyway, even the operating system made it hard to change the time (which it doesn't), it wouldn't prevent clients spoofing packets. Use the time that the server receives the message.